# How do I inject a message into Postfix's queue?

Tags: email, message-queue, postfix-mta

I am working on an application that quarantines and routes email.  Let's say in this application that I have an email message in a directory of my choosing and it has been scanned by our software and is considered "clean".  How do I inject this message back into Postfix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you simply use `sendmail` ?

Comment: That's a possibility.  I neglected to mention that I'm using Ruby, so I also might use Tmail to read the message and Net::SMTP to connect to Postfix for delivery.

Answer (score 1):

I recognize that this is a rather old question. For the benefit of people stumbling across this question:

The qpsmtpd SMTP daemon has a Postfix Queue-Plugin to inject mails into Postfix. The plugin directly talks to the cleanup daemon of Postfix. It shall be rather easy to adapt/port that code (it's written in perl).

http://www.qpsmtpd.org/